# Evenly Space Visible React Native ScrollView Elements

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

I currently have a ScrollView that lists text items. I am paginating it with 4 items on each page. For an example, I list out the month names, and this works well because 12 is divisible by 4. I get 3 pages, 4 items per page, where the items are spaced equally. I do this using justifyContent: 'space-around'. This makes my example work for the purpose of showing how I'd like things to be aligned, but it isn't flexible when there are more items

If I add an extra text element called "ALL" at the beginning, what I would like is All-March on page 1, evenly spaced. Apr-July on page 2 looking the same, Aug-Nov on page 3 the same, and Dec by itself on page 4, on the left side. I have added a snack as well as the code below. Hopefully I have provided enough details.

https://snack.expo.io/PjQ0EG6eq

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {
  View,
  ScrollView,
  useWindowDimensions,
  StyleSheet,
  Text
} from "react-native";
import moment from "moment"

const HorizontalTextCarousel = props => {
  const numberOfItems = React.Children.count(props.children);
  const itemsPerInterval = props.itemsPerInterval ? props.itemsPerInterval : 4;

  const [width, setWidth] = React.useState(0);
  const [totalIntervals, setTotalIntervals] = React.useState(0);

  const adjustContent = w => {
    setWidth(w);
    let t = Math.ceil(numberOfItems / itemsPerInterval);
    console.log(t)
    setTotalIntervals(t);
  };

  return (
    <View style={{width: '100%'}}>
      <ScrollView
        contentContainerStyle={[styles.scrollViewContainer, {width: `${100 * totalIntervals}%`}]}
        horizontal={true}
        alwaysBounceHorizontal={true}
        bounces={true}
        decelerationRate="fast"
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        scrollEventThrottle={200}
        onContentSizeChange={(w, h) => adjustContent(w)}
        pagingEnabled={true}>
        /*UNCOMMENT THE FOLLOWING LINE TO SEE THINGS NOT ALIGN CORRECTLY. 
        /WANT IT TO LOOK JUST LIKE IT DOES WHEN THE NUMBER OF ITEMS IS EVENLY
        DIVISIBLE, EXCEPT WITH AN EXTRA PAGE WITH 'DEC' ON IT*/

        //UNCOMMENT THIS
        <Text style={styles.monthText}>ALL<Text>
        {props.children}
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
};

const getMonths = () =>
  [...Array(12)].map((_el, i) => (
    <Text style={styles.monthText} key={i.toString()}>
      {moment()
        .month(i)
        .format('MMM')}
    </Text>
  ));

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <View style={{flex:1, width: '100%', backgroundColor:'blue'}}>
      <View style={{marginTop: 100}}>
        <HorizontalTextCarousel>
          {getMonths()}
        </HorizontalTextCarousel>
      </View>
    </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  scrollViewContainer: {          
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
  },
  monthText: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 24
  }
})

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by having a function to wrap items for each page under another View. Then I paginate those wrapper views instead of the individual items.

So my render function outputs something like this. Even though there are 6 items for the scroll view, I group them into views with a maximum of 4 items in each view.

```
  return (
<View style={{width: '100%'}}>
  <ScrollView
    contentContainerStyle={{
      width: `${numberOfWrapperViews*100}%', //in this example this would be 200% b/c 2 wrapper views (Math.ceil(total items to render (6)/max items per page(4))
      backgroundColor: '`',
      justifyContent: 'space-evenly'
    }}
    horizontal={true}
    alwaysBounceHorizontal={true}
    bounces={true}
    decelerationRate="fast"
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
    scrollEventThrottle={200}
    pagingEnabled={true}>
  <View
      style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-evenly'}}>
      <Text style={{justifyContent: 'space-evenly', flexDirection: 'row'}}>ABC</Text> 
      <Text style={{justifyContent: 'space-evenly', flexDirection: 'row'}}>EFG</Text>
      <Text style={{justifyContent: 'space-evenly', flexDirection: 'row'}}>ABC</Text> 
      <Text style={{justifyContent: 'space-evenly', flexDirection: 'row'}}>EFG</Text>
    </View>
    <View
      style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-evenly'}}>
      <Text style={{justifyContent: 'space-evenly', flexDirection: 'row'}}>HIJ</Text> 
      <Text style={{justifyContent: 'space-evenly', flexDirection: 'row'}}>KLM</Text>
    </View>
  </ScrollView>
</View>
```

);
};